# PHP WordPress register form required checkbox

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, required

I am trying to make my WordPress registration form GDPR compliant where the user needs to check a checkbox that they accept our privacy policy.

I have successfully made the checkbox by using the hook `register_form`.

However, I am having issues making the checkbox field required. I have tried with required true in my array but it doesn't seem to work. I can someone explain what I can do in order to make the checkbox required?

```
add_action( 'register_form', 'login_extra_note' );

function login_extra_note() {

    woocommerce_form_field( 'privacy_policy_reg', array(
        'type'          => 'checkbox',
        'class'         => array('form-row privacy'),
        'label_class'   => array('label-for-checkbox checkbox'),
        'input_class'   => array('form__input-checkbox input-checkbox'),
        'required'      => true,
        'label'         => 'Jeg har læst og acceptere <a href="https://example.dk/privatliv/" target="blank">Betingelser & Privatlivspolitik</a>',
    ) );

}
```

Comment: try: 'required' => 'required'

Comment: @IonS Warning: Use of undefined constant required - assumed 'required'

Comment: Ok, go back to 'required' => true. [This link](https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/checkout-fields.html#optional_or_required) may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was related to no error message being associated to the chekbox field. I managed to solve it by adding an error to the checkbox field:

```
// add registration chekbox field
add_action( 'register_form', 'login_extra_note' );

function login_extra_note() {

woocommerce_form_field( 'privacy_policy_reg', array(
   'type'          => 'checkbox',
   'class'         => array('form-row privacy'),
   'label_class'   => array('label-for-checkbox checkbox'),
   'input_class'   => array('form__input-checkbox input-checkbox'),
   'required'      => true,
   'label'         => 'Jeg har læst og acceptere <a href="https://example.dk/privatliv/" target="blank">Betingelser & Privatlivspolitik</a>',
));

}

// Error registration form
function my_registrationform_error( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {

    if ( ! (int) isset( $_POST['privacy_policy_reg'] ) ) {
    $errors->add( 'demo_error', __( '<strong>FEJL</strong>: Du skal accepter VIFT Betingelser & Privatlivspolitik!', 'my_textdomain' ) );
        }
    return $errors;
}

add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'my_registrationform_error', 10, 3 );
```